# Refer to the long range of variables in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I was wondering how to refer to the long range of variables in the array.

I have fields called Check1, Check2, Check3 up to 60. I'd like to refer to the range of Check1-Check60.

```
//Do I have to mention ALL the 60 fields here?
var fieldsToValidate = ["Check1", "Check2", "Check3", "Check4", "Check5", "Check6", "Check7"];
```

Is there a cleaner/shorter way to write this?

edit:

**Forgot to mention I am using JavaScript for Acrobat, here's the snippet:**

```js
//Do I have to mention ALL the 60 fields here?
var fieldsToValidate = ["Check1", "Check2", "Check3", "Check4", "Check5", "Check6", "Check7"]; //etc.  
var emptyFields = [];  
for (var i in fieldsToValidate) {  
    var f = this.getField(fieldsToValidate[i]);  
    if (f.valueAsString==f.defaultValue) {  
        emptyFields.push(f.name);  
    }  
}  
 
if (emptyFields.length>0) {  
    app.alert("Error! You must fill in all required Fields:\n" + emptyFields.join("\n"));  
} else {  
    this.getField("Signature1").display = display.visible;  
}
```

Comment: When you say you have to `refer` to each element in an array, what do you mean?  Are you doing any type of validation?  If so, what is your goal?

Comment: To refer a range of an array you should simply slice it like  `fieldsToValidate.slice(0,60)` which will return a shallow slice of `fieldsToValidate` array which has a portion of the items starting from 0 (inclusive) up to 60 (exclusive).

Answer (score 0):

If all your field are simply like `Check[n]` where n is incremented by 1. You can do the following

```js
var fieldsToValidate = []

for (let i = 1; i <= 60; i++) {
  fieldsToValidate.push("Check" + i);
}

console.log(fieldsToValidate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a generator:

```js
console.log([...function*(n) {
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) yield `Check${i + 1}`; 
}(60)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This method works for me, Thank you!

```js
var fieldsToValidate = []

for (let i = 1; i <= 60; i++) {
  fieldsToValidate.push("Check" + i);
}

console.log(fieldsToValidate);
```